# PLAY CONSOLE WEB VIEW Cross App Scripting Vulnerability

Tags: javascript, android, webview, google-play-console

I'm struggling with my web view App, the google play team said that my app is vulnerable to cross-app scripting. I've tried to enable safe browsing (set it to `YES`) but the warning from google still appears.

Google recommends setting `setJavaScriptEnabled` to `false`, but that's not a valid option for me because I use javascript on my webview app.

Does anybody solve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

### **Option 1:**

Ensure that affected activities are not exported
Find any Activities with affected WebViews. If these Activities do not need to take Intents from other apps you can set `android:exported=false` for the Activities in your Manifest. This ensures that malicious apps cannot send harmful inputs to any WebViews in these activities.

### **Option 2:**

Protect WebViews in exported activities

If you want to set an Activity with an affected WebView as exported then we recommend that you make the following changes:

1. *Protect calls to evaluateJavascript and loadUrl*
2. *Prevent unsafe file loads*

For more details go to [Google Help: Fixing a cross-app scripting vulnerability](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9084685?hl=en-GB)